# How to display inline divs outside and inside container?

Tags: html, css

How can I display `div`s like this? (red line is container)

[image: SS]

I've tried making grey containers bigger `width` (example `1000%`) then moving it to left by `-950%`, but after this I couldn't display `div`s inline.

Maybe someone has ideas how could I do this?

```
<div class="container">
<div id="contacts" class="gmlogic-target">
    <div class="contacts-wrap">
        <div class="contacts-left">
            <div class="contacts-text">
                <div class="contacts-text-wrap-left">
                    <h3>Get in touch</h3>
                    <div>
                        <span>Email</span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Our address</span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Mobile phone</span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Call between</span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contacts-social">
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img alt="facebook" src=""></a>
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img alt="facebook" src=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="contacts-right">
            <div class="contacts-text">
                <div class="contacts-text-wrap-right">
                    <div>
                        <span>Company name</span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Company code</span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>VAT code</span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Address</span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Phone</span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span>Email</span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nhdjbL71/)

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nhdjbL71/1/)?

Comment: grey background should extend outside container class, like in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `flexbox` +  `position` with `calc()` using viewport units `vw` and `%`

```css
.container {
  width: 90%; /* changed for demo */
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: red solid 1px
}
.contacts-wrap {
  min-height: 172px;
  padding: 100px 0;
  display: flex
}
.contacts-left,
.contacts-right {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  width:50%
}
.contacts-left {
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%)
}
.contacts-right {
  right: calc(-50vw + 50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="contacts" class="gmlogic-target">
    <div class="contacts-wrap">
      <div class="contacts-left">
        <div class="contacts-text">
          <div class="contacts-text-wrap-left">
            <h3>Get in touch</h3>
            <div>
              <span>Email</span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>Our address</span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>Mobile phone</span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>Call between</span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="contacts-social">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
          <img alt="facebook" src="">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com">
          <img alt="facebook" src="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="contacts-right">
        <div class="contacts-text">
          <div class="contacts-text-wrap-right">
            <div>
              <span>Company name</span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>Company code</span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>VAT code</span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>Address</span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>Phone</span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <span>Email</span>
              <span></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how could I stretch .content-left div's left side till it hits the browser's left side? Same with right side. Is it possible to make that space between .content-left and .content-right divs would depend on .content-middle width?

Comment: How about "Is it possible to make that space between .content-left and .content-right divs would depend on .content-middle width"?

Comment: try this: `.contacts-social {width: 100%;}` not sure what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry mixed class names. .contacts-social should be max 250px. How to make distance between .contacts-left and right 250px?

Comment: `.contacts-social {width: 250px;}`

Comment: It doesn't work like that. http://i.imgur.com/RDOmacB.jpg there's a giant gap between contacts-left and contacts-social

Comment: On bigger resolution it looks in the previous picture. But thanks, I got the point how to fix this.